# Depth of almost complete intersection rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay-rings, complete-intersection

Let $R$ be a regular local ring and let $I \subset R$ be an almost complete intersection ideal, that is, $\mu(I)=\text{ht}(I)+1$ where $\mu(I)$ is the number of minimal generators of $I$ and $ht(I)=\text{dim}(R)-\text{dim}(R/I)$. Is it true that $\text{depth}(R/I)=\text{dim}(R/I)-1$? If not, is there any other relation between almost complete intersections and depth?

Comment: I think what you wrote is not what you had in mind. In most cases you expect  $\operatorname{depth}(R/I)=\operatorname{dim}(R/I) =\dim(R)-\operatorname{ht}(I)  $, which is far from what you wrote.

Comment: What you wrote is true in the case where $R/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay, which is not the case for almost complete intersections.

Comment: (But you are right about height and codimension, so I edited accordingly).

Comment: $R/I$ can very well be Cohen-Macaulay — take $R=k[[x,y,z]]$, $I=(xy,yz,zx)$.

Comment: I see. But can we at least prove that $\text{depth}(R/I) \geq \text{dim}(R/I) -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, depth can be zero. Let me give an example.

Let  $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth variety of dimension $d$ which is subcanonical (this means $K_X=O_X(*)$ for some integer $*$) and NOT arithmetically normal (this means the map $H^0(O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(l))\to H^0(O_X(l))$ is not onto for some $l$).

Let $m=n-d$ and choose general $m$ hypersurfaces $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ vanishing on $X$ of large enough degree. Then, $V(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=X\cup Y$ where $Y$ is another $d$ dimensional variety and the $f_i$s define a complete intersection. One has an exact sequence,
$$0\to K_X(*)\to O_{X\cup Y}\to O_Y\to 0,$$
for a suitable integer $*$.

Let $R$ be the homogeneous co-ordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let $I$ the defining ideal of $X$. Taking global sections in the above sequence gives,
$$0\to H^0_*(K_X)=A\to H^0_*(O_{X\cup Y})=R/(f_i)=S\to S/A\to 0.$$

One has a natural inclusion $R/I\to A$, by our assumption on $K_X$ and this inclusion is not an isomorphism. The cokernel $T$ is non-zero of finite length. Composing this inclusion with the inclusion of $A\to S$, we get an inclusion, $R/I\to S$ and let the cokernel be $B$. Notice that $B$ is almost complete intersection and by snake lemma we have an exact sequence $0\to T\to B\to S/A\to 0$ and thus depth of $B$ is zero.

To get a regular local ring, we may localize at the irrelevant maximal ideal of $R$ without changing the final claim.

There are several ways of constructing $X$ as above. Let me describe one. Take a non-degenerate smooth complete intersection $X$ of dimension $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ where $n>2d$. Then, take a generic projection to $\mathbb{P}^n$.